# Why is a TV star in the classroom?

Tags: plot-explanation, hairspray

In [Hairspray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairspray_(2007_film)), Link Larkin (played by Zac Efron) is a TV Star in the movie.

But in this scene, he is shown sitting in a classroom, why so?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Link Larkin is still a teenager and so is still **required** to receive an education.

So he attends school just like any other teenager which would have been the norm at the time that *Hairspray* is set.

> The **teenagers featured on the show attend Tracy and Penny's school**, among them Amber von Tussle and her boyfriend **Link Larkin**, the lead male dancer
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairspray_(2007_film))</sup>

Note that since then many child actors will receive dedicated lessons in a special area set aside by the production company for such a purpose often from a tutor rather than attend *regular school*...although some do.

For instance...

> The state of California mandates that studio teachers be on any set where children are working, to monitor child labor laws. **They're responsible for ensuring that the students do 15 hours of schoolwork a week, the state requirement for 1st through 12th graders.** They're also supposed to keep an eye out for safety practices.
>
> <sup>[Source](http://www.scpr.org/blogs/education/2013/07/22/14301/child-actors-get-schooled-meet-the-woman-who-s-spe/)</sup>